# How can I call google apps script with HTTP GET or POST?

Tags: http, https, google-apps-script, arduino

I have a problem with HTTPS Protocol. 
I have a project with Arduino, it only allow use HTTP Protocol.
How can i call a GAS(HTTPS) with GET or POST method of HTTP Protocol?
I need store some data from Arduino into Google Spreadsheet.
Thanks all !

Comment: Are you asking what the code should look like in arduino?  To make an Apps Script save data to a sheet, you need to create a Stand Alone Apps Script, publish it, get the URL and then just make a request to the URL.  You'd need to put data into the URL search string, or have Apps Script make a fetch request back to the data source.

Comment: @SandyGood Thank for your answer ! I can  make a Stand Alone Apps Script to store data into Google Spreadsheet. And I have a URL like this: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz6wWT7CdW-w09zOxG1zhFJ6ksdsjKx4b2c7K3xgaSz42hhUM4/exec?var=value      But it using HTTPS protocol. There for, I can not call this URL from Arduino

Comment: Have you tried just removing the "s" on https, and see if it will run?  `http://script.google.com/macros/s/etc"`  Also, do you need a return value or not?

Comment: @SandyGood I tried it ! It run and return error "301 Moved Permanently"

Comment: Sorry.  Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: @SandyGood ! Thank you so much ! I will use my solution (Arduinno -> HTTP Server -> GAS -> Spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is the solution with the wifinina librairie like explained here https://recursos.citcea.upc.edu/iot/exemple/scripts.html
but i think it is not avaible for esp32
In my project with a nodemcu 12-E i had to use the HTTPSRedirect.h
( //https://github.com/electronicsguy/HTTPSRedirect)
this worked for me but:
i had too to changed some types  char * :

```
const char ssid[] = "ssidbox";  // char * ssid="..." provoquait une erreur   !!!!!
const char password[] = "wifipass";         //replace with your wifi password

const char host[] = "script.google.com";    // char * host="..." provoquait une erreur  de meme avec String!!!!
const char GScriptId[] = "AKfycb....."; // Replace with your own google script id
```